# Mysql data retrieval

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a attendance management system for my company. For that I have a table in my mysql database called PRESENCE. The table looks like below.

> +------+-------------+---------+----------+-----------+--------+------+------+
>
> |  pid | shift_time  |  timein | timeout  | workhours |  date  | uid 
>   |  day |
>
> +------+-------------+---------+----------+-----------+--------+------+------+

I have two buttons in my html for check in and check out. Employees login daily and click the check in button when they come to office. When they click the check in button i insert a new row to the above table with

```
pid(auto incremented),
timein(server time),
timeout(default value 00:00:00),
date(server date),
uid(logged in employee id),
day(present day like monday,tuesday etc.)
```

And when they click the check out button i just update the timeout value to server time and calculate workhours and update that too.

In my html i have written a select query to select all rows for a particular employee id from this table and show the output. Now my problem is that if a user is not checking in for any date i want that date to be shown as `"absent" or "no-shift".` I am not really sure how to do this. Any ideas and help would be greatly appreciated. I need to finish this project as soon as possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you make an assumption that a worker is expected to work five week days, then for the 'absent' or 'no-shift' case you could show the days there is no shift entry. These missing rows would need to be explained by the worker.

At a minimum i think you need to add a 'type' column to the table which would  be an enum of (SHIFT,ABSENT).

In general you single table schema seems a bit restrictive for these extra use cases.

Comment: I do get the idea what you say now. But i really couldn't figure out the way to do it. In my case the database gets a new row whenever a user is clicking the check in button from the webpage. So if one worker is not going to come for a day, obviously there is not going to be any row in the database for that particular date for that particular worker. So now how do i know that the worked has not come for that day? I am new to php and mysql, so sorry if I am not understanding your idea clearly.